# How do you get a system color from properties and show the color

Tags: c#, graphics, brush

I am using C# / Windows Forms. I am saving a `System.Drawing` color into the program settings then displaying it in a picture box. That works, now the last part to do is to get the color that's in properties and put it into code.
The setting is called `missingHL`

I have:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LimeGreen, e.Bounds);
```

Where `LimeGreen` is, is what I need to replace with the color from properties.
I tried this:

```
Color c1 = Properties.Settings.Default.missingHL;
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.c1, e.Bounds);
```

however this does not work.

If you need more information I will try to provide it, just ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c1), e.Bounds);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I appreciate you helping me out with this.

Comment: Since `SolidBrush` implements `Disposale` you have to wrap it into `using`